# Excel 2016 insert copies cells is incredibly slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large sheet (approx 60K rows by 50 cols). I'm trying to copy several (2 to 8) rows into clipboard and then insert copied cells. This operation takes more than a minute to complete!

I've tried disabling automatic calculations, initiating this operation from VBA, like this:

```
Range("A1").Insert xlShiftDown
```

to no available. If I paste (Ctrl-V) rather than insert it works like a snap.

Any ideas how to work around this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve? Why are you trying to insert rows? etc. etc.

Comment: How are you copying and choosing the cells? Maybe your bottleneck isn't just on that final line of code. Are you using loops?

Comment: New data should be in the top lines of the worksheet, that's why I have to insert rows rather than go to the end of table and paste them there.

Comment: Can you sort the sheet quickly enough? If so I have an idea...

Comment: I'm not using any loops. I just copy several rows on the same sheet, right click and choose "Insert copied cells" from pop-up menu

Comment: Sorting works relatively fast, takes about 10 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can paste the data quickly enough use that instead of inserting, then sort the rows:

1. In an empty column on the first row of data type the number of rows you want to insert plus 1 (e.g. to insert 3 rows type 4)
2. Add the next number in the next row, then select both cells and autocomplete the column so that each row has an increasing number
3. Paste the new data at the end of the old data, immediately after the last row
4. Number the first row pasted as 1, the 2nd as 2 etc
5. Sort the sheet ascending on the number column then delete the column

Comment: In fact, adding seq numbers to 60K rows would take some time, too - but the idea is helpful, indeed!

Comment: Really that should be sub 1 second on most computers, I'm guessing you have a great many formulas going on, or perhaps some events that are firing on the worksheet change event?

Comment: Quite a number of array VLOOKUPs, but I really doubt this is the reason. See, I tried disabling automatic recalculation, it didn't help.

Must be something else ... but I ran out of options trying to guess what it is.

Comment: Are you inserting into the table that the VLOOKUPS reference?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Absinthe's algorithm, here's the code:

```html
    Sub InsertRows()
    Dim SourceRange, FillRange As Range
    Dim LastCol, LastRow, ActRow, CpdRows As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    If Application.CutCopyMode <> xlCopy Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With ActiveSheet
        
        LastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ActRow = ActiveCell.Row

        .Paste Destination:=.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
        
        CpdRows = .UsedRange.Rows.Count - LastRow

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(ActRow, LastCol + 1), .Cells(ActRow + 1, LastCol + 1))
        SourceRange.Cells(1).Value = CpdRows + 1
        SourceRange.Cells(2).Value = CpdRows + 2
        
        Set FillRange = .Range(.Cells(ActRow, LastCol + 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1))
        SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange
        
        For i = 1 To CpdRows
            .Cells(LastRow + i, LastCol + 1).Value = i
        Next i
        
        .Range(.Cells(ActRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow + CpdRows, LastCol + 1)).Sort Key1:=.Cells(ActRow, LastCol + 1), _
             Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
        
        .Columns(LastCol + 1).Delete
        
    End With
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

It's works definitely faster than "insert copied cells" and it seems it's accelerating after the 1st use (I mean, when I run the macro for the 2nd, 3rd etc time it works even faster than on the 1st run). There are the cons, too. For example, named ranges do not automatically expand when you insert the lines in this manner.

And the most significant problem of this method: Excel does not move the borders with the cells when sorting. Therefore, the border structure will be ruined. The only workaround I know of is to use conditional formatting for the borders.

This all being said, it's a good workaround